# Maximizing the area of a rectangle inscribed within a right angle triangle

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

[image: Context image]

Whilst revising for an upcoming exam, I'm stumped on the following problem:

---

"A right-angled triangle has sides 12 cm, 16 cm and 20 cm as shown. A rectangle is inscribed in the triangle with one side along the hypotenuse and a vertex on each of the other two sides of the triangle. What are the dimensions of the largest such rectangle?"

---

CURRENT THOUGHTS:

The area of a rectangle is given by:

$A = l \times w$

I would assume that the way to solve this is to express area, $A$, as a function of $x$, where $x$ is the magnitude of the length and width in centimeters, and then solve for $\frac{dA}{dx}$ to determine a maximum for area. However, I am struggling with how to express the length and width of the rectangle. I assume that the use of similar triangles in the right angle triangle in the top of the figure, and the bottom right are necessary in doing so. However, I'm uncertain as to how to do this.

Could someone please show me how. I have successfully solved other optimization problems, so it is just this specific scenario which I'm not understanding.

Comment: You have the triangle dissected into a rectangle plus three similar triangles. Two of these have bases on the hypotenuse, and the same height. The hypotenuse of the third also maps to the hypotenuse. Therefore you have a constraint.

Comment: The small triangle on the bottom right is similar to the large triangle, and the hypotenuse of the small triangle is a side length of the rectangle. Let that side length be $l$, then represent the other side length of the rectangle in terms of $l$ using similar triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{f}{d} = \frac{20}{12} \quad \frac{e}{12-d} = \frac{16}{20} \qquad 
A = f\cdot e = \frac{4}{3}d \, (12-d) \quad \to A_\text{max}:d=6$$
[image]